# Is there a way to delete rows from azure synapse dedicated sql table from Synapse notebook spark data frame

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-synapse-analytics

```
    schema = StructType([
       StructField("Name", StringType(), False),
    ])

    df = spark.createDataFrame([("Test",)], schema)
    df.write
     .option(Constants.SERVER, "test.sql.azuresynapse.net")
     .option(Constants.TEMP_FOLDER, "abfss://test@test.dfs.core.windows.net/test")
     .mode("append")
     .synapsesql("TestDatabase.dbo.Files")
```

The above code is helping me to add records to the dedicated sql pool table but I need to check if the record exists remove and insert or directly update the record. Is there any possible way to update or delete based on dataframe?